# How to enable a two-finger drag on a mac in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, macos, user-interface

In a Silverlight 4 application I have a **ScrollViewer** which I enable the user to scroll with the **mouse wheel** by using **SetIsMouseWheelScrollingEnabled():**

```
<ScrollViewer 
    x:Name="CodeBoxScrollViewerModelSingular"
    tk:DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
    Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerCodeBoxStyle}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SingularModelFileContent}"
         Style="{StaticResource TextBoxCodeBoxStyle}"/>
</ScrollViewer>

CodeBoxScrollViewerModelSingular.SetIsMouseWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
```

However, someone tested it on a **Mac** and said:

> The only problem I noticed on a quick
>   test was that I
>   couldn't scroll down by using a
>   **two-finger drag**, which has been
>   standard UI behavior on the **Mac** for
>   several years now.

**Is there any way to enable a "two-finger drag" on the Mac as you can enable mouse wheel scrolling?**

Comment: I am also facing similar problem for my silverlight data grid.2 finger mouse scroll is not working for silverlight data grid.how did u solve your problem.please share with ue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the MouseWheel input is only supported on Windows, this is a limitation on the Mac and its input notification system I believe.

OS X presents the two-finger drag to the platform as a mouse wheel operation.