# Implementing 2 Finger scroll in silverlight based application on safari on mac system

Tags: html, macos, silverlight, dom, managed

I am developing silver light 4/5 based web application.2 finger scroll on data grid is not working on safari browser.how to enable 2 finger scroll for silver light data grid on mac safari.

Answer (score 0):

Mac is a very hard platform to cope with. Do you need a Xaml soultion or maybe a Javascript bridge to the html dom which captures the motion?

Keep in mind:
Other stackoverflowers tried it already: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065360/how-to-enable-a-two-finger-drag-on-a-mac-in-silverlight)

Regards,
- Tobi

Comment: can please share link or sample for both.

Comment: A good way to start is this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293515/Calling-Silverlight-Method-from-Javascript-and-Jav).